# How to select records that have attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

If I have a model "User" with a attachment "avatar", how can I select all Users with an avatar?

ie, I want to do something like:

```
users_with_avatars = User.where(avatar: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since attachment usually a string to a file, so I think, selection can be done with negation. For *`carrierwave`* you can search over the mounted attributes:

```
users_with_avatars = User.where.not(avatar: nil)
```

for *`paperclip`* you can search over `avatar_file_name` field:

```
users_with_avatars = User.where.not(avatar_file_name: nil)
```

or over `avatar_file_size` field:

```
users_with_avatars = User.where("avatar_file_size > 0")
```

Comment: that doesn't work.  the attachment is an image file, using paperclip.

Comment: @Will yes, but over which field did you search?